# Pandas and "doubled double quote" escaping in CSV

Tags: python, pandas

Sometimes CSV data is formatted like this

```
col1,col2,col3
a,b,"this field has an embedded quote character ("") in it"
```

Which is intended to be parsed as

```
col1 | col2 | col3
a    | b    | this field has an embedded quote character (") in it
```

That is, the field-quoting character is escaped by doubling it.

The Python `csv.reader` module handles this just fine, as long as [`csv.Dialect.doublequote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.doublequote) is `True`.

How can you do this in Pandas?

Comment: Note that you can also escape the character or enclose the string in single quotes.

Comment: @Acccumulation this would be data I received from someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: I found the answer before I had even finished posting*

Use `pd.read_csv(..., doublequote=True)`

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', quotechar='"', doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

swapping out `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` for `QUOTE_MINIMAL`, or something else, as appropriate.